TVD of parametric Poisson distributions
Let $p_1(n)$ and $p_2(n)$ be Poisson distributions with parameters $\lambda_1=\lambda_1(x)$ and $\lambda_2 = \lambda_2(x)$ for $x\in \mathbb R$. The total variation distance of these distributions is
\begin{align}\text{TV}(p_1, p_2)(x)&=\frac12\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|p_1(n)-p_2(n)|
\\
&= \frac12 \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left|\frac{e^{-\lambda_1(x)}\lambda_1^n(x)}{n!}-\frac{e^{-\lambda_2(x)}\lambda_2^n(x)}{n!}\right| \end{align}
for fixed $x$, which can then be integrated to find the total statistical distance
$$D = \int dx \ \text{TV}(p_1, p_2)(x). $$
The sum looks pretty intimidating, but I thought there might be standard results to help here since the Poissonian is such a fundamental distribution. I've been looking around, but I haven't been able to find similar computations, if not approximations there are inapplicable to my case (for instance, when $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are not simply related to each other as functions of $x$). Is it possible to do this computation analytically?

If $\lambda_1(x)<\lambda_2(x)$, then $TV$ is of the form $(a+b e^{\lambda_2(x)-\lambda_1(x)})/e^{\lambda_2(x)}$.  For example, $TV(3,11)=\frac{13977 e^8-3389017}{720 e^{11}}$

The first step would be to calculate $TV$.  Here I use Mathematica but I'm sure that Maple, MATLAB, and others can do so.
tv[λ1_, λ2_] := Sum[Abs[Exp[-λ1] λ1^n/n! - Exp[-λ2] λ2^n/n!]/2, {n, 0, ∞}]

tv[2, 3]

$$\frac{10 e-17}{2 e^3}$$
But it might be more productive to get rid of the ABS (absolute value) function.  The difference in the probability mass functions will be zero for a value of $m$ when
$$e^{-\lambda_1} \lambda_1^m=e^{-\lambda_2} \lambda_2^m$$
The largest integer value ($n_0$) no larger than the solution will be the floor of $m=\frac{\lambda_2-\lambda_1}{\log (\lambda_2)-\log (\lambda_1)}$.  If $\lambda_2\geq\lambda_1$, then
$$TV=\sum _{n=0}^{n_0} \left(\frac{\exp (-\lambda_1) \lambda_1^n}{n!}-\frac{\exp (-\lambda_2) \lambda_2^n}{n!}\right)=\frac{\Gamma (n_0+1,\lambda_1)-\Gamma (n_0+1,\lambda_2)}{\Gamma (n_0+1)}$$
where $\Gamma(n_0, \lambda)$ is the incomplete gamma function.  This will be much, much faster to compute than the brute force formula initially given.
The integral you contemplate certainly depends on how $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are functions of $x$ (and maybe doesn't even exist).
